# Google Apps Script JDBC Connect via hostname broken

Tags: google-apps-script

There seems to be an issue with Google Apps Script JDBC Connection in recent days, where connection via a hostname fails, but specifying an IP works.

Error: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.

We first noticed this last Thursday.

The below code has been working flawlessly for 18 months or so.

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myhost.com:3306/dbname","myuser","mypass");
```

It now necessary to use the IP instead.

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.20.30.40:3306/dbname","myuser","mypass");
```

Hoping one of the GAS team can comment.

Rob
Google Apps GPF TC

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the progress on this problem on our issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1856